# Fastest way to toggle <secure> true or false inside web.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, https

I'm developing a java base app which has to be deployed in PROD to Google App Engine. I need the set the `<secure>true</secure>` flag inside web.xml when comes time to deploy to PROD. However I'm testing with my `appengine:devserver` on my workstation and I'm using http (not https) so I have to set it to `<secure>false</secure>` or comment it out.

Question: what's the easiest way to automate this? I know it's possible with maven profiles but is there something Google plugin for Eclipse made or another way I'm missing? My project is Maven based and I'm starting the devserver either from command line or within the IDE...

Comment: Can you set Java System Properties or O/S environment variables in GAE?

Comment: Yes it's possible to set system properties inside appengine-web.xml manifest file which becomes part of the deployed WAR file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that if I start only the webapp using appengine:devserver we don't need to care about true. So this is not a problem if I simply change the way I start the webapp. The problem occurs only if you start the webapp with Tomcat, jBoss or your own jetty server. However I consider a good practice to be able to run the application from something else than GAE just to be sure we aren't binded to a specific engine (server agnostic pattern)...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [SessionCookieConfig](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig.html) and setting it programmatically? (e.g.: depending on environment variables)

Comment: Like this? http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/javaee6/web/servlet/sessioncookieconfig-war/src/java/web/servlet/sessioncookieconfig_war/ConfigListener.java.shtml

Comment: Yeah, exactly. You'll be able to test it using maven-surefire-plugin's systemPropertyVariables or IDE's test launch params and in the PROD env just launch the VM with -D arg.

Comment: Would be happy to use that solution but Google App Engine still does not support Servlet api 3.x which is a shame. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3091

Comment: Well.. In this case you're left with Maven profiles, filtering or manipulating the manifest.. I'm sorry that it didn't help - Google should've fixed the GAE long ago